# как задать диапазон дат в animation.FuncAnimation в аргументе frame

Tags: анимация, pandas, matplotlib

Пытаюсь настроить анимационный график в matplotlib, вдохновившись примером на

```
https://colab.research.google.com/github/pratapvardhan/notebooks/blob/master/barchart-race-matplotlib.ipynb#scrollTo=eiZafT-XNL8f
```

У меня имеется следующий датафрейм:

```
    board_name  finished_date   labels             count
0   RUCRA_Tasks     2019-06-03  Auto Grade to validate      9
1   RUCRA_Tasks     2019-06-03  Int IO - Full IQ pr. del.   5
2   RUCRA_Tasks     2019-06-03  Internal IO - Full IQ       2
3   RUCRA_Tasks     2019-06-03  Manual Uwing for CLR        6
4   RUCRA_Tasks     2019-06-04  Auto Grade to validate      3
5   RUCRA_Tasks     2019-06-04  Int IO - Full IQ pr. del.   3
6   RUCRA_Tasks     2019-06-04  Internal IO - Full IQ       2
7   RUCRA_Tasks     2019-06-04  Manual Uwing for CLR       10
8   RUCRA_Tasks     2019-06-04  Visa-Payment History        2
```

когда я пытаюсь в конце вывести анимацию графика указав период дат, у меня не идет динамика графика с начальной даты до конечной

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))

animator = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, draw_barchart,frames=range('2019-06-01', '2019-09-01'))
HTML(animator.to_jshtml())
```

я понимаю, что в аргументе frames нужно именно написать итерацию по дате, а не то что я дал. Но не получается :(

Answer (score 1):

Получилось сделать и все заработало, но код а) грамоздкий и б) корявый

```
from dateutil import rrule, parser

df['finished_date'] = df['finished_date'].astype(str)
df_date = df['finished_date'].to_list()

date_range = list(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, dtstart=parser.parse(df_date[0]), until=parser.parse(df_date[-1])))
dt = []                       
for el in date_range:
    dt_new = datetime.strftime(el, '%Y-%m-%d')
    dt.append(dt_new)
```

и уже в frames вставляю dt

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))

animator = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, draw_barchart,frames=(dt))
HTML(animator.to_jshtml())
```